# Extract text/number from a string in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have some strings in 1 column like this:
BOPP MỜ 925x25/CPP MỜ 920x20

BOPP MỜ 750x20/PE CXH 750x6/SCPP CXH 750x30

("x" actually wrote is "*")

How could I extract each material (text string) to each column?, also their width (the first number) and thickness (the second number)?

I've try
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"([^\d+\n]+)") to get the first material and

=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\d+") to get first width

But after that I don't know what to do?

Comment: What about `SPLIT()` function?

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,split(regexreplace(Σ,"(\D) (\d)|\*|/","$1|$2"),"|"))))
```

[image]

*Modified formula since OP needs to segregate each single `material+width+thickness` into separate rows; the following is for `first material`*

```js
=let(Σ,split(regexreplace(A2,"(\D) (\d)|\*|/","$1|$2"),"|"),
     choosecols(Σ,1,2,3))
```

Comment: Thank you. That works, but in actually, I often have only 1 string in a sheet, but I need to extract it several times, and they not in a same row. For example: BOPP MỜ 750x20/PE CXH 750x6/SCPP CXH 750x30, I need BOPP MỜ in a cell, 750 in a cell, 20 in a cell, they are in same row, the next material in another row but not always right below.

Comment: Added the formula to your [Sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XODOlFWjUzNQlUVjuEmYmtCBAJI21pzQppD_EYl1rxI/edit#gid=105966514). the formula is in ***Cell B2*** and the results of all rows are populated automatically.

Comment: thank you for you help, but how to extract it like:

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution

```
=MAP(A2:A,LAMBDA(form,IF(form="",,REDUCE(TOROW(,1),SPLIT(form,"/"),LAMBDA(a,c,{a,REGEXEXTRACT(c,"(.+?) (\d+(?:-\d+)?)\*(\d+(?:-\d+)?)")})))))
```